# Android Virtual Device is not starting

Tags: xubuntu, 64-bit, android, adt

I am facing a problem to run the AVD in my Xubuntu 14.04 64bit version. Before that I used Xubuntu 32bit and that time my ADT(32bit) worked. But now I am using 64bit ADT and 64bit OS. everything is okay but the AVD is not starting and showing me the problem below:

Starting emulator for AVD 'Avd_name'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/media/Disk_name/Folder_name/And_Dev/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory

Please help me..... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 64-bit Ubuntu
You can try this to install 32 lib to run 32bit app in ubuntu 64bit

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```